# Why i'm getting exception 'Space_Soldier_A_LOD1(Clone)' AnimationEvent 'FootStep' has no receiver! Are you missing a component?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I didn't have this exception an hour ago.
And i'm getting it on any animation i'm trying now.

On HumanoidWalk for example i'm not getting the exception but this animations that are part of a package for no reason started to make this exception/s maybe half an hour ago.

I created a new animator controller for the character and created new blend tree and then in the blend tree tried to change some walk animations by default i used the HumanoidWalk and then animation not my own from the package of walk too and it was working fine. Then i tried another animation in the blend tree and then this exception came up.

[image: Exception001]

The script i'm using that is attached to the character:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Soldier : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var inputVelx = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var inputVely = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        transform.Rotate(0, inputVelx, 0);

        anim.SetFloat("VelX", inputVelx);
        anim.SetFloat("VelY", inputVely);
        anim.SetBool("Aiming", false);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Aiming", !anim.GetBool("Aiming"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Animation of your Animator (Unity -> Window -> Animation), you can see a small white rectangle inside the Event Line. This white rectangle represents an animation event, which is fired when the animation is in the current step.
More about Animation event:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html

This Animation Event tries to call a method (function) "FootStep" on the gameObject (in your case soldier). 
What you need to do is either delete this Animation Event (white rectangle), or extend your Soldier class by FootStep function:

```
class Soldier : MonoBehaviour
{
   ... 

   public function FootStep() {
      // do something
   }

   ...
}
```

Hope that helps.